# Replacing exact word in a file in unix ksh

Tags: unix

I have a file called test.txt in UNIX and it has the contents like below

day sunday day
 monday day night
 night day tuesday

Now i want to replace day with night in unix (KSH) but sunday ,monday,tuesday values shouldn't be changed(exact day value oly to be chaged). ie expected result set follows,

night sunday night
 monday night night
 night night tuesday

Can somebody help.. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sed 's/^day/night/; s/ day / night /g' file
```

Output:

```
night sunday night monday night night night night tuesday
```

To edit the file in place saving the original as file.old:

```
sed -i.old 's/^day/night/; s/ day / night /g' file
```

Comment: Actually,you should also show him how to input text from file and then replace it!

Comment: Does someone know how to say `^ or \s` so you can do it in one go?